# Issue while running Jitsi videobridge

Tags: java, docker, maven, jitsi

I tried to clone jvb and run with maven accordint to [this](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge/blob/master/README.md). And i did it using docker. My dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install default-jdk -y

RUN apt-get install -y maven


CMD ["sleep","1000000"]
```

My docker-compose file is

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  jvbz:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./src:/jvb:rw"
      - "./.m2:/root/.m2:rw"
    working_dir: /jvb
    ports:
      - "8086:1999"
```

but when i run using maven it shows the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] jvb-parent
[INFO] jvb-api-parent
[INFO] jvb-api-common
[INFO] jvb-api-client
[INFO] jitsi-videobridge
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jvb-parent 2.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-maven) @ jvb-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) @ jvb-parent ---
Error: Could not find or load main class org.jitsi.videobridge.MainKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jitsi.videobridge.MainKt
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:982)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:929)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:457)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] jvb-parent ......................................... FAILURE [  0.702 s]
[INFO] jvb-api-parent ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] jvb-api-common ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] jvb-api-client ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] jitsi-videobridge .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.118 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-31T14:55:55Z
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/47M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project jvb-parent: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

You can view the source code [here](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge)
Jitsi Videobridge is an XMPP server component that allows for multiuser video communication. Unlike the expensive dedicated hardware videobridges, Jitsi Videobridge does not mix the video channels into a composite video stream, but only relays the received video channels to all call participants. Therefore, while it does need to run on a server with good network bandwidth, CPU horsepower is not that critical for performance.

Can someone please help me with this.